# Convert string decimal to hex decimal

Tags: c

How can I convert a string decimal to hex decimal and add them to char pointer? Why does the `memcpy(value + 2, &value_value, value_length);` not work, the result is `0x02 0x01` and not `0x02 0x01 0x4f`.

```
#include <string.h> /* strlen */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdint.h> /* int32_t */
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol */

int main()
{
    char value_type = 0x02;
    char *value_value = "79"; /* Must convert to 4f */

    char value_length;
    int32_t num = strtol(value_value, NULL, 10);
    if (num < 255)
        value_length = 0x01;
    else if (num < 65536)
        value_length = 0x02;
    else if (num < 16777216)
        value_length = 0x03;
    else if (num < 4294967295)
        value_length = 0x04;

    char *value = malloc(2 + value_length);

    memcpy(value, &value_type, 1);
    memcpy(value + 1, &value_length, 1);
    memcpy(value + 2, &value_value, value_length);

    /* expectation: 0x02 0x01 0x4f */
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(value); i++)
        printf("%02x\n", value[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(value + 2, &value_value, value_length); ` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `memcpy(value + 2, &num, value_length);`

Comment: Also did not copy the string terminator to use `strlen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong variable:

```
memcpy(value + 2, &num, value_length);
```

Also, you must not trait your value as string, as far as it uses binary value. Change your code to:

```
    /* expectation: 0x02 0x01 0x4f */
    int dumplen=len+2;
    for (int i = 0; i < dumplen; i++)
        printf("%02x\n", value[i]);
    return 0;
```

Comment: yes its works, but I will use `memcpy(value + 2, &value_value, value_length);`. So how can I copy `num` to `value_value`?

Comment: @Sam you cannot: `value_value` is a string, and `num` is a number.

Comment: @Sam, value_value=malloc(value_length);memcpy(value_value, &num, value_length);

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(value + 2, &value_value, value_length);
```

this expression copies `value_length` bytes from `&value_value`.

Given that it's declared as

```
char *value_value
```

`&value_value` is read as a `pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-char`. So effectively you're reading the pointer value.

How to solve:

```
memcpy(value + 2, &num, value_length);
```

Another problem with your code:

you're using `strlen(value)` while `value` is not a null-terminated C-string. It's just an array of bytes that you fill with your data.

How to fix:

don't use `strlen` in this case, you know the size of the array: `2 + value_length`. For clarity you may put it to a separate variable.